# working with android intents how to pass arguments between father and the intent h in

Tags: android, android-intent

Assuming i want to open another activity from my current activity and i want to pass arguments such as in my case difficulty level how do I do it?

```
newGameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public  void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(countryCityGameMenu.this,GameScreen.class);    
            startActivityForResult(i, GlobalDataStore.STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE);

        }
    });
```

is there a way to pass those arguments in the calling ?

can someone show an example explaining

what send activity should do
what the new born activity should do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use extras like this:

i.putExtra(varName, value);

Comment: can you explain more ? 
i read this one on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras(android.content.Intent)

but still an example would b more efficient 
thanks for everything.

Answer (score 4):

As ben already mentioned you can add this data to the intent inside an extra bundle.

An extra bundle stores data as a key value pair of native java data types. 
You can add data to the intent via the [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) methods.

In the new Activity you can retrieve this data via the getExtra methods of the Intent. For example the [getStringExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29) method.

To get the intent that started the current activity just use the getIntent() method from activity.

Answer (score 0):

Not a big fan of this approach... but unfortunately it sends to be the only way to do it in android...

Comment: send activity side :

           Intent i = new Intent(countryCityGameMenu.this,GameScreen.class);    
            i.putExtra("title","my name is slim shady")
startActivityForResult(i, GlobalDataStore.STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE);
 invoked side :
           Intent i = this.getIntent();
           String mystr= i.getStringExtra("title");
 seems to b odd solution does somebody knows how to solve it differently?

Answer (score 0):

fine.. U can also use StartActivity(intent); Thats enough to pass