# Putting arguments to Activitiy.this in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, parameter-passing

how can I call MyActivitiy.this, but put arguments to it or to its Bundle?

My Code:

```
   OnSwipeTouchListener onSwipeTouchListener = new OnSwipeTouchListener(MyActivitiy.this) {
            @Override
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                //your actions
            }
        };
```

Comment: This was asked on the post. You can find it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2990078/2925157

Comment: I have to recall the same activitiy with different params on swiping.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't seem to be very clear. But, consider declaring a Context ( set it equal to MyActivity.this) and using that as the parameter for your OnSwipeListener.

The way to communicate with an Activity is via Intents. In whatever code you use to start your Activity, go:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(someContext, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("myKey", "whateverValue");
```

In your Activity's onCreate() method, use:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message intent.getStringExtra("myKey", "aDefaultValueJustInCase");
```

Once that Activity is started, the String message will acquire the value "whateverValue".

As to using its Bundle, you probably only want to do that to recreate your Activity (say you're returning from another Activity, or pressed Back). Documentation for that is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

Hope that answered your question. If not, please provide us more details and we will probably be able to provide more specific answers.